# Blog post index page - show excerpts only

Tags: 2007, blog

what would be the best way to only show excerpts (say first 200 words) of the posts on the blog's index page in SP2007?

Even better, could we add a field to the blog post to add a custom teaser?

Happy for answers to include less technical options e.g. web parts.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to use the content query webpart with a custom xslt template to format the output

there are already too many posts and questions in this, so if you want to know more you can search around the forum for CQWP or check out this very detailed post from Erik Swenson

http://erikswenson.blogspot.se/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-content-query-for-blog.html